# Specify Selenium Firefox Node host as a variable inside a Docker container

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to set up Selenium in Docker Swarm. It's a standard setup, so hub + replicated Firefox nodes. Since I'm using different networks for different components of the Swarm I've encountered a problem with networking.

Although Firefox Node IP is let's say `10.0.1.19` it gets reported to the Selenium Hub as `172.19.0.4`. Hub cannot connect to this IP since it's outside the network created for Selenium and node gets timeout.

I found out I can set `host`, `port`, and `remoteHost` arguments of Firefox containers but since everything is dynamic I cannot hardcode those values. Therefore I thought about doing something like this in my `docker-compose.yml` file inside Firefox Node definition:

```
    environment:
      - SE_OPTS="-host $$HOSTNAME -port 5555 -remoteHost http://$$HOSTNAME:5555"
```

If `$HOSTNAME` variable could be used this would solve my problem immediately. Unfortunately while checking Hub logs I see:

`java.security.InvalidParameterException: Error: Not a correct url to register a remote : http://$HOSTNAME:5555"`

Apparently the argument is not changed to its value before sending it to the hub. I'd like to send the right IP or hostname of the Firefox node. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was editing Firefox Docker entrypoint file and manually adding

```
export MYIP="$(cat /etc/hosts | grep $HOSTNAME | sed 's/\s.*$//' | tr -d '\n')" 
REMOTE_HOST="http://$MYIP:5555" 
REMOTE_HOST_PARAM="-remoteHost http://$MYIP:5555"
```

This way the node always sends its correct IP based on the IP found inside `/etc/hosts`